# How to achieve progressive rendering in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, progressive-web-apps, code-splitting

How to achieve progressive rendering in VueJS, only in client side?

[image]

Comment: It is not the progressive loading, it is some kind of lazy loading functionality what you looking for. But lazy loading has nothing to do with Progressive Web Applications at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a project, **progressive web applications** is recommended as [**vuejs-templates/pwa**](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa) or Normally, the lazy loading code will use these. [**Lazy Loading in Vue using Webpack's Code Splitting**](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/07/16/Lazy-load-in-Vue-using-Webpack-s-code-splitting/)
If it is preload, it will use [**preload-webpack-plugin**](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/preload-webpack-plugin)

> This example a good project : [**vue-hackernews-2.0**](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0)

Comment: vue-hackernews has SSR, which is gets rendered on server side. But thanks for the tip.